# Onclick no funciona correctamente PHP

Tags: javascript

Hola intento abrir un elemento con el evento onclick, pero necesito 2 clics para poder abrir el modal en dicho evento.

Añado codigo HTML también, supongo que es por la función, pero no lo tengo demasiado claro, por si alguien me puede hechar una mano.

Gracias.

Adjunto el código:

```
  function modal(num){
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal_" + num);
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn_" +num);
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
   }


document.getElementById("myBtn_1").onclick = function(){
    modal(1);
  }



echo "<div id='myModal_$num' class='modal'>";
  echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
  echo "<span class='close'>&times;</span>";
  echo "<h3 style='color:#145C99; text-decoration: underline;'>ARCHIVOS</h3>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</div>";
    echo "<i id='myBtn_1' class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true'>";
```

Comment: Podrías agregar tu código de HTML?

Comment: Tienes un `btn.click` dentro de una función que llamas al hacer click, yo creo que eso puede estar haciendo algo para que no te lo muestre correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos errores, el primero es que llamas al metodo onclick del elemento myBtn_1 dentro del metodo modal, el segundo error es que creas un metodo onclick para el elemento btn que no es necesario, con la primera llamada al dar click en myBtn_1 es suficiente.

Acomoda este codigo

```
    function modal(num){
  

    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal_" + num);
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn_" +num);
    
    modal.style.display = "block";
  
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    };
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
   };

};
document.getElementById("myBtn_1").onclick = function(){
    modal(1);
  };
```